# How remove startup disk?

Tags: uninstall

How in Ubuntu remove startup disk?
[image]

Comment: Is there any particular reason you are trying to remove it? Are you trying to solve some other problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open a terminal and enter the command

```
sudo apt remove usb-creator-gtk
```

You can further run `sudo apt autoremove` to remove its unused dependecies.